# Is there an option in chrome devtools (or other browsers) to temporary change browser's main font-size?

Tags: css, user-interface, browser, google-chrome-devtools, font-size

I have set the `:root {font-size: 10px}` property to use rems or pixels as units for users, that scales the browser's font *(Chrome example: Settings => Appearance => Font Size = Large)*. So every time I want to see how chosen units affects UI, I need to go to settings and apply different font scales. Also it affects all tabs and I want to avoid this behavior.

Is there a simple way to do this instead of getting into the browser's settings?

[upd]

1. ctrl+ / ctrl- **does not** work the same as font scale in browser, which i'm asking about.
2. I know how to change scale in settings, i'm asking for an options to quickly change it in devtools.

[upd] [difference between zoom and browser's font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSBeo.png)

Comment: Are you referring to Zoom in the browser itself? If yes then Cmd+ or Ctrl+ will increase the font-size of the page, and it will persist for that domain.

Comment: No, i am referring to the browser setting. It does not work the same as zoom, the difference is in the "rem" unit's behavior.

Comment: I see so you're asking for increase/decrease text size from devtools. I dont think there is an option to do that from the DevTools, but you can install a Chrome extension like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-text-only/jamhfhbppcmkgghlkeieococonlbppjg) to achieve the same thing.

Comment: How about using the font-size options like "large", "medium", etc on the `body` in DevTools? Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQFTG.png). It seems to work pretty much the same way as the Font-size setting in the browser.

Comment: @PankajParashar Unfortunately, neither body font-size nor extension can do the trick :(
Body font size affects only font size that wasn't overwritten, and the extension forces all text to change and ignores css. Additionally, I use rems not only for font-size but also for margins, paddings, etc.
So, looks like, the only option is to use Chrome settings :(
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All of you who advise zooming the browser via ctrl+ and similar, open your apps on android mobile and change the font size in the mobile settings, and see what it did to the appearance of your apps. So you will figure out what is the subject of the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: since the question is about DevTools.

In the Styles pane, you can apply font-size values like `medium`, `large` etc on the body tag. It seems to work pretty much the same way the Browser's **Font size** setting works.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not affect margins, paddings and etc. Also, it affects only font sizes that wasn't overwritten.
Seems like there is no option to emulate global browser font size fast, for one tab and I need to stick to chrome settings :(
Thank you!